# How get Data from a JSON Object Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{   
 "action" : "get",
 "application" : "2c5ca3b0-be74-11e4-8ff3-f7af49a474ef",
 "params" : {
 "ql" : [ "select * where username='pqr'" ]
},
 "path" : "/logs",
 "uri" : "https://api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs",
 "entities" : [ {
 "uuid" : "97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e",
 "type" : "log",
 "created" : 1425036869840,
 "modified" : 1425036869840,
 "metadata" : {
  "path" : "/logs/97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e"
 },
 "password" : "pqr",
 "username" : "pqr"
 }],
 "timestamp" : 1425359738746,
 "duration" : 15,
 "organization" : "serv-d",
 "applicationName" : "demo1",
"count" : 1
  }
```

This is the server side response to my app and I want to get the user name and password values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON response into a Javascript object. Then you can access the properties.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

The username and password are in an array that's in the `entities` property, so you can access them as:

```
var username = obj.entities[0].username;
var password = obj.entities[0].password;
```

Comment: the JSON is already an object, isn't the parse() method for when it's in string?

Comment: He said that was the response from the server. That means it's a string, servers can't return objects directly.

Comment: oh, didn't notice that thanks

Comment: i'm learning json and javascript, could you pls take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2z6opbm4/, it gives out an uncaught syntax error, but not using parse() outputs correctly

Comment: @war1oc The argument to `JSON.parse()` should be a string, not an object.

Comment: @war1oc See http://jsfiddle.net/2z6opbm4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in a variable, say in variable data.

```
var data = {   
     "action" : "get",
     "application" : "2c5ca3b0-be74-11e4-8ff3-f7af49a474ef",
     "params" : {
     "ql" : [ "select * where username='pqr'" ]
    },
     "path" : "/logs",
     "uri" : "https://api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs",
     "entities" : [ {
     "uuid" : "97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e",
     "type" : "log",
     "created" : 1425036869840,
     "modified" : 1425036869840,
     "metadata" : {
      "path" : "/logs/97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e"
     },
     "password" : "pqr",
     "username" : "pqr"
     }],
     "timestamp" : 1425359738746,
     "duration" : 15,
     "organization" : "serv-d",
     "applicationName" : "demo1",
    "count" : 1
};
//logging username and password fields
console.log(data.entities[0].username, data.entities[0].password);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON behaves like key value pair kind of collection. Assign this Json to Javascript variable and then you can get the values of JSON with respective key like

```
     var myJson = 
      {
         "action" : "get", "application" : "2c5ca3b0-be74-11e4-8ff3-
          f7af49a474ef", "params" : { "ql" : [ "select * where   
           username='pqr'" ] }, "path" : "/logs", "uri" : 
          "https://api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs", "entities" : [ 
          { "uuid" : "97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e", "type" : 
           "log", "created" : 1425036869840, "modified" :  
             1425036869840, "metadata" : 
             { "path" : "/logs/97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e"  
              }, "pas           sword" : "pqr", "username" : "pqr" 
             }],  "timestamp" : 1425359738746, "duration" : 15, 
               "organization" : "serv-d", "applicationName" : "demo1",
                  "count" : 1 };


            var action = myJSON.action;
             var uri = myJSON.uri; and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store it as "obj", then you can do `obj.entities[0].username` (and likewise for password.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring it as `data`, You can use `data.entities[0].username` to access username.

```js
var data = {
    "action": "get",
    "application": "2c5ca3b0-be74-11e4-8ff3-f7af49a474ef",
    "params": {
        "ql": [
            "select * where username='pqr'"
        ]
    },
    "path": "/logs",
    "uri": "https://api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs",
    "entities": [
        {
            "uuid": "97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e",
            "type": "log",
            "created": 1425036869840,
            "modified": 1425036869840,
            "metadata": {
                "path": "/logs/97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e"
            },
            "password": "pqr",
            "username": "pqr"
        }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1425359738746,
    "duration": 15,
    "organization": "serv-d",
    "applicationName": "demo1",
    "count": 1
};
alert(data.entities[0].username)
alert(data.entities[0].password)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var yourData = {   
 "action" : "get",
 "application" : "2c5ca3b0-be74-11e4-8ff3-f7af49a474ef",
 "params" : {
 "ql" : [ "select * where username='pqr'" ]
},
 "path" : "/logs",
 "uri" : "https://api.usergrid.com/serv-d/demo1/logs",
 "entities" : [ {
 "uuid" : "97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e",
 "type" : "log",
 "created" : 1425036869840,
 "modified" : 1425036869840,
 "metadata" : {
  "path" : "/logs/97b0fd0a-be74-11e4-9324-b3bd8af7859e"
 },
 "password" : "pqr",
 "username" : "pqr"
 }],
 "timestamp" : 1425359738746,
 "duration" : 15,
 "organization" : "serv-d",
 "applicationName" : "demo1",
"count" : 1
}
```

Because username and password is data of entities- that is an array of one element member
you may access the username data

```
var username = yourData.entities[0].username
```

Similarly for password